# Как правильно использовать media queries ?

Tags: html, css, html5

При достижении 900 - px , мне надо чтобы `.logo` заняло 100 процентов ширины в главном `.container` а `.navigation` ушло вниз под `.logo` как отдельный блок с размеров в 100% ширины. Можно ли это сделать с Media Queries ?

```css
.navigation {

    float: right;
    border: solid;
    color: brown;
    min-width: 70%;
    max-width: 70%;
    padding: 2px;
}

.nav{

    float: right;
    border: solid;
    color: blueviolet;
    min-width: 98%;
    min-height: 75px;
    max-height: 75px;
    max-width: 98%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">

        <div class="navigation">

            <div class="nav">

                <ul class="list">

                    <li id = "home">Home</li>
                    <li id = "login">Login</li>
                    <li id = "register">Register</li>
                    <li id = "contact-us">Contact Us</li>
                    <li id = "about-us">About Us</li>
                    <li id = "our-location">Our Location</li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="logo">

            <h5>CouponSystem</h5>

            <h6>Choose the service you like! </h6>
        </div>


    </div>


@media (max-width: 900px){


    .logo {
        
        min-width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Просто заключите media queries в тег style

Comment: Буду рад примеру кода!

Comment: вот http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media и вот https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries просто и понятно.

Comment: приблизительно http://codepen.io/diproart/pen/BQyRBG, просто демонстрация. (в примере используется `scss`, просто для краткости)